# weird issue with Shell script while retrieving data from pubmed

Tags: shell, curl

I am trying to extract abstracts from Pubmed. I am running the following script which works fine when we run with a small number of pubmed IDs around 50-60 and when I tried to run with more pubmedIDs, we get error with curl

*curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL*

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
count=0
while read -r line;
do (echo -n 'PMID:'"$line")
   ruby -e 'print "\t"'
   ruby -e 'print "\n"'
   curl "http://togows.dbcls.jp/entry/ncbi-pubmed/$line/abstract"
   ruby -e 'print "\n"'
count=$((count+1))
done < "$filename"

#total no. of abstracts extracted#
echo $count
```

Please help me with solving this issue.

Example PubmedIDs are:

```
15531828
11791095
10708056
11359038
14984170
14996372
12705689
10970410
15745253
11582918
15660174
12238577
11846869
15310339
11284241
10865179
11519913
10834973
15121927
12904598
10783021
12719941
12434895
11556849
15794973
15504558
11283055
11884969
15496247
12150169
11668160
14723257
11452319
12754871
12652386
15484803
11368111
11683083
12071816
15822796
11032337
10782588
14643389
10948134
15655738
12359815
12384847
14743041
11055595
15292894
15118207
12382086
12601766
15304469
14640166
15060685
10879334
12506595
11055604
12937770
12042153
14970250
14580749
10835062
15293830
12181084
15602860
15583308
12769313
11134428
15702553
12940584
12394811
11040149
14647094
11950120
11865552
11490992
11036798
12481673
12454294
10921974
11450280
15449969
11605811
15473159
11827304
12012636
12777561
15619887
12734212
12792381
12699859
15001934
12075759
12009822
12665273
12558335
11876456
11791097
```

I tried with wget but output is not in the required format. wget creates folder for each pubmedID.

Output format is

```
PMID:15531828
text text text text text text
text text text text text text

PMID:11791095
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
```

Thank You.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using the "expensive" call to `ruby echo`, when `printf "\t\n"` will do the same and is a shell built-in, requiring NO creation of a new process. AND, more importantly, it's not clear what is your required output. Do you want an html file for each pubmedID? Good luck.

Comment: I would wrap the call to curl with `set -vx ; curl .... ; set +vx` and then edit your question above with the output from a successful execution and then a failing execution of the call to `curl`.

Comment: @shellter Thank you. I agree with you and I updated my code with printf. I removed ruby and used simple printf. I used set option and I found the mistake. The file got carriage returns and I removed the returns. It is working with small data set. I will try with large data set and update the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the inconvenience. It is not the problem with curl or shell or ruby. I found that my IDs file got carriage returns (\r). I didn't expect that Linux generated files got carriage returns. I solved this with the help of shellter's inputs from the comments.

I updated the code as well by removing ruby options and used the printf.

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' input_file.txt # to remove carriages
```

Updated code is

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
count=0
while read line;
do (echo -n 'PMID:'"$line")
   printf "\t\n"
   set -vx; curl -f "http://togows.dbcls.jp/entry/ncbi-pubmed/$line/abstract"
   printf "\n"
count=$((count+1))
done < "$filename"

#total no. of abstracts extracted#
echo $count
```

It may useful for someone

Thanks

Comment: Good show! Always happy when someone solves their own problem. See the list of other bash resources on right side of tha page at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98569/bin-bash . Also (while not appropriate to this Q) good habit to check failing code at https://shellcheck.net . When using shellcheck uou need to include the proper `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever) as the first line of your code. Keep posting and good luck!